# Enable developer mode on LG WebOS tv

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I'm developing a simple app on a LG webOS smart TV.
Since I had no luck running my app from the usb drive, I'm trying to use the developer mode from Eclipse IDE.
The thing is:
I've added a new target configuration, pointing to the physical TV ip.
When I try to connect, a passphrase is required. I've tried something like 123456
A pop up appears: "Please verify the properties on the target and also make sure the key server in Developer mode app is ON in TV"

How do I enable Developer Mode on these TV?

Comment: Hi what do you mean developer mode on LG WebOS? Do you want only run your developed app? If yes you have to "build" you ipk file in lg webpage https://developer.lge.com/secure/Login.dev

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already built this "package" and it works from the usb, but this way is not practical for repetitive tasks. I heard there's some kind of "LG partner" account, and if you log onto the TV, a magic "developer mode" is activated, and it will provide you with a passphrase for connecting Eclipse to TV.

Comment: I dont know "magic developer mode". But you are right load eveerytime from USB is not so practical. I made workaround => I have one index.html file and inside this file i redirect to application location.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually, it is what I am doing, since I found no way to connect IDE to physical TV. So far is working fine, but still would like to know which is the proper way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With webOS 2 only some specific TVs where enable to debug and run apps on 22 January 2016 WebOS 3.0 released.

Now you can create an account and then install from LG Content Store the developer mode then when you connect your IDE or Cli the tv will give you the passphrase.

Detailed guide:
http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/

Comment: In my experience webOS-TV and webOS Signage are different in this respect. Any idea how to turn on debug mode on a webOS Signage screen?

Comment: @dbexec: this URL goes to 404 page, can you provide working URL.

Comment: @regeint a bit late but the URL is up and also use can you the link here https://web.archive.org/web/20190903062332/http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/

Comment: The detailed guide instructions helped me get it connected.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

If you are connected with same network you can do remote deployment from webOS TV IDE. First you need to create a developer account from
https://webostv.developer.lge.com/login

Then install **Developer mode** app from **LG Content Store**

1. On remote press Home button
2. Go to LG Content Store
3. Search 'Developer mode' on LG Content Store
4. Install 'Developer mode' app

After installation you can use LG account for login purpose  from Developer mod application you can enable Developer mode and find passphrase

Comment: 1) Go to http://developer.lge.com

2) Click Sign In at the top right corner of the screen.

3) Select the CREATE ACCOUNT tab. The Select Country pop-up will be shown

THERE IS NO SIGN-IN BUTTON ON THAT PAGE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it with WebOS 2 (and as a reference, you can use pictures from LG's website to visualize these steps): https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/getting-started/developer-mode-app

1. Make sure your computer is connected to the same router as your physical TV.
2. In your LG TV; navigate to `LG Content Store` and install `Developer Mode` app.
3. In your LG TV; enable `Key Server`.
4. Using your computer; you have two possible routes to access the TV remotely:

   - CLI: You can acquire minimal CLI tools from: https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/tools/cli-installation#step1
   - *GUI: Alternatively, download the FULL version if you want to have a GUI using webOS TV IDE application (with e.g. Windows)*
5. After the tool is unpacked (or when installation is complete):

   - CLI: navigate to the extracted folder in your terminal/CMD, e.g:

     - Linux: `cd /usr/share/webos-tv-cli/bin`
     - Windows: `cd C:\Users\$USERNAME\Downloads\webOS TV CLI win 1.12.4-j27\CLI\bin`)
   - *GUI: in the bottom right corner you'll see `Target Configuration`, click on `New Connection`.*
6. Configure credentials:

   - CLI: Execute this command to add a new connection: `ares-setup-device`

   ```
   ? Select add
   ? Select a device webOS_TV
   ? Enter Device IP address: 192.168.xxx.xxx (ENTER YOUR TV'S IP HERE)
   ? Enter Device Port: 9922 (THIS PORT IS HARDCODED WITH WEBOS 2)
   ? Enter ssh user: prisoner (THIS USERNAME IS HARDCODED WITH WEBOS 2)
   ? Enter description: new device
   ? Select authentication password
   ? Enter password: [hidden] (LEAVE THIS FIELD EMPTY BY PRESSING ENTER)
   ? Save ? Yes
   ```

   - *GUI: Provide these details:*

   ```
   Device Type: LG Smart TV
   Device Name: webOS_TV
   IP Address: 192.168.xxx.xxx (ENTER YOUR TV'S IP HERE)
   User ID: prisoner (THIS USERNAME IS HARDCODED WITH WEBOS 2)
   Password: (LEAVE THIS FIELD EMPTY)
   Port: 9922 (THIS PORT IS HARDCODED WITH WEBOS 2)
   Description:
   ```
7. Provide the Passphrase:

   - CLI: Execute: `ares-novacom --device webOS_TV --getkey` and enter your `Passphrase` from the `Developer Mode` app in the TV.
   - GUI: In the bottom right corner, right-click on `webOS_TV` and select: `Properties` where you'll have to add `Passphrase` from the TV (do **NOT** modify the `Password` field).
8. Verify if this worked

   - CLI: Run `ares-device-info webOS_TV`
   - *GUI: Right-click on `webOS_TV` and select `Connect`.*

Extra: I used this to sideload a app with:

- CLI: Run: `ares-install --device webOS_TV FILE.ipk` to install it onto your TV.
- GUI: Unfortunately it looks like the included SDK is out of date even after checking for updates (`Help > Check for Updates`). Nonetheless it should be possible to install apps with `webOS Menu > Install IPK` if you don't encounter `[Install] ares-install ERR! Error: Command '/bin/rm -rf /media/developer/temp && /bin/mkdir -p /media/developer/temp' exited with code=1 (signal: undefined)` error. You can still use the CLI once you download it (using step 4 and see the relevant command above) as the connection is fully configured at this point!