# How to enable developer mode on LG webOS 3.0 TV

Tags: webos, lg, smart-tv

I want to test a simple web app on my LG webOS 3.0 SmartTV using the Developer Mode app from LG Content Store and the webOS IDE on my laptop.

I've ensured that my TV and laptop are on the same wifi network and installed the Developer Mode app from the Content Store on the TV. But after I've logged in with my LG Developer ID and password, I can't seem to figure out how to navigate to the "Dev Mode Status" button and enable it.

How do I enable Developer Mode on my LG webOS TV? (Model: 65UF680V-ZA)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733500/enable-developer-mode-on-lg-webos-tv

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read through that one. My problem is that I don't know how to navigate to the enable/disable button with my remote control. I've pretty much tried pressing all the buttons on the remote and nothing seems to engage the Developer Mode button on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem in this thread. http://developer.lge.com/community/forums/RetrieveForumContent.dev?detailContsId=FC03095252

It turns out that it isn't possible to navigate in the Developer Mode app with a regular remote control which only has arrow keys and no pointer function.

Luckily I had a wireless USB keyboard with a built-in mouse trackpad that I could use to bring on the screen cursor and ultimately enable the developer mode button.

EDIT: The Dev Mode button can now be enabled by using the regular TV remote control.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is plugged in mouse... or something else with cursor